# cannot get response from api

Tags: java, android

I have API news It consists of elements
web name, key, country 
It's all good, and I first tested the link :
https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=eg&apiKey=e80f949de1a34b94804188af28f08f44
And then I built the required class ,and set up a interface and put it Headers , Query 
,and when I called it, I found a mistake.

```
/// 
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/";

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(){
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
           }
       return retrofit;
    }
}


///-----


public interface GetData {

      String API_KEY="e80f949de1a34b94804188af28f08f44";

       @Headers("X-Api-Key:"+API_KEY)
       @GET("/v2/top-headlines")
       Call<List<Response>>getAllHeadlines(@Query("country") String country);

}
//- MainActivity 

   GetData service = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetData.class);
      Call<List<Response>> call = service.getAllHeadlines("eg");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Response>>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Response>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<Response>> response) {
                Log.d("print","Don"+response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Response>> call, Throwable t) {
               Log.d("print","nON"+t.getMessage());
            }
        });


// Log.d 

 D/print: nONExpected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Comment: I hope that is a free api key and not one that you get actually billed for, in the later case you should really not share it.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the Gson Converter. You're expecting a List but the json is returning a json object instead of a json array right at the start. Check out your model so you can change it according to json.

Comment: So you are saying the `List<Response>` within `Call<List<Response>>` is the problem because the API does not return a list at the top level?

Comment: @luk2302 yes, exactly that. Check out your model to see if it makes sense to change it according to the json or, if the json is the one that is badly formatted, take a look at implementing your own Gson Type Converter so you would intercept the conversion, loop through each key value pair in the object and, supposing that this value is mappable to your model, cast it to the model then you would be able to return your list.

Comment: I suspect it is the model which is wrong here, not the API / Json, since the latter is defined by an external service which cannot be changed. If you could include the details from my and your comment into your answer that would improve the answer further.

Comment: When I made a change. call<List<Response>> to

Comment: But why don't we use Call<List<Response>>